# Declare a TDateTime as a Const in Delphi

Tags: delphi, date, operator-overloading, constants, tdatetime

As far as I know there is no way to do this, but I am going to ask just in case someone else knows how to do this.  How can I declare a date as a const in Delphi?

The only solution I have found is to use the numeric equivalent, which is **kind of a pain** to maintain because it is not human readable.

```
const
  Expire : TDateTime = 39895; // Is actually 3/23/2009
```

What I would like to be able to do is something like this:

```
const
  Expire : TDateTime = TDateTime ('3/23/2009');
```

or

```
const
  Expire : TDateTime = StrToDate('3/23/2009');
```

So let me know if this is a feature request or if I just missed how to do this (yeah, I know it seems like an odd thing to want . . . .)

Comment: Great question - I've often wanted to do this (more for times than for dates, but the principle is much the same - eg I want to put 6:45pm into a TDateTime as a const, etc). I invariably end up doing something like your first example, with comments - and it's a pain when I later need to change it!

Comment: This looks like something GExperts or DLangExtensions should be able to do, either as an expert to enter date and or time to create a properly commented constant, or as a preprocessor converting string to TDateTime. Allowing ISO 8601 formats only should remove all ambiguity.

Comment: @Mghie - good point. A GExperts solution would be perfectly acceptable to me. It's when I have to get the calculator out to start doing divisions that I get frustrated. :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, my reaction is a bit late, but here's a solution for the newer Delphi's.

It uses implicit class overloaders so that records of this type can be used as if they are TDateTime variables.

```
  TDateRec = record
    year,month,day,hour,minute,second,millisecond:word;
    class operator implicit(aDateRec:TDateRec):TDateTime;
    class operator implicit(aDateTime:TDateTime):TDateRec; // not needed
    class operator implicit(aDateRec:TDateRec):String; // not needed
    class operator implicit(aDateRec:String):TDateRec; // not needed
  end;
```

Implementation:

```
uses DateUtils;

class operator TDateRec.Implicit(aDateRec:TDateRec):TDateTime;
begin
  with aDateRec do // Yeah that's right you wankers. I like "with" :)
    Result := encodeDateTime(Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second,Millisecond);
end;

class operator TDateRec.Implicit(aDateTime:TDateTime):TDateRec;
begin
  with Result do
    DecodeDateTime(aDateTime,Year,Month,Day,Hour,Minute,Second,Millisecond);
end;

class operator TDateRec.Implicit(aDateRec:TDateRec):String;
begin
  Result := DateTimeToStr(aDateRec)
end;

class operator TDateRec.Implicit(aDateRec:String):TDateRec;
begin
  Result := StrToDateTime(aDateRec)
end;
```

Now you can declare your dates like this:

```
const
  Date1:TDateRec=(Year:2009;month:05;day:11);
  Date2:TDateRec=(Year:2009;month:05;day:11;hour:05);
  Date3:TDateRec=(Year:2009;month:05;day:11;hour:05;minute:00);
```

To see if it works, execute the following:

```
ShowMessage(Date1); // it can act like a string
ShowMessage(DateToStr(Date1)); // it can act like a date
```

If you really want to replace all your TdateTime variables with this, you probably need to overload some other operators too (Add, subtract, explicit, ...).

Comment: +1 for the solution and +1 again for `with`, although I despise its use :-)

Comment: I took this and added my own additions to it... `FriendlyDate`, `FriendlyTime`, and `FriendlyDateTime`

Answer (score 12):

The only? possible way, but probably not what you are looking for:

```
const
{$J+}
  Expire: TDateTime = 0;
{$J-}

initialization
  Expire := EncodeDate(2009, 3, 23);
```

Comment: May as well just declare it as a var instead of a const.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but at least my solution uses the const keyword ;)

Comment: Jim, my typo originates from your post :P

Comment: Ooops, you are right.  The first Expire was spelled wrong.  I will fix it.  I thought it might when I saw it, but then I only looked at the 2nd two instances.

Comment: Please don't ever do this.  I hate {$J+}

Answer (score 11):

I tend to simulate **const** dates with a function. Technically they're a little more *constant* than the "pseudo-constant" assignable typed **const**'s.

```
function Expire: TDateTime;
begin
  Result := EncodeDate(2009, 3, 23);
end;
```

**NOTE** the use of `EncodeDate` rather than `StrToDate`. `StrToDate` is affected by regional settings meaning there's no guarantee a string will be interpreted as would be expected.

For example, did you know that there's a strange a group of people who think it makes sense to "shuffle" date parts into an inconsistent order of significance? They use middle, then least, then most significant part (e.g. '3/23/2009') **<cheeky grin>**. The only time that logic makes sense is when you turn 102 years old - then you can claim your age is 021.

> For the *premature optimisers* out there, if the function is called so frequently that the nano seconds required to encode a date becomes an issue - you have a far **bigger** problem than this minor inefficiency in the name of readable, maintainable code.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to do this because interpreting a date litteral in itself is not deterministic, it depends on the convention/locale you follow.
'1/4/2009' is not in January for any French person for instance, and having the compiler translating as January 4th would make it a fool's compiler ;-)
Unless the compiler implements some (well documented) "magic" bijective function for pairing a date value and a display representation... And anyway, half of the planet would not like it.
The only non ambiguous way I see now is to provide the value even if it looks like a pain...
... my $0.02

Comment: It only depends on the locale if the language is defined to be sensitive to the locale. Floating-point literals aren't locale-sensitive; they simply don't accept commas as the decimal separator. No reason a date-time literal couldn't have similar restrictions on format.

Comment: EncodeDate and EncodeTime are deterministic so would be useable **if**  they could be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

No, Delphi doesn't support that.

Your first idea would be a request for date-time literals distinct from ordinary floating-point literals. I found [QC 72000](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=72000), which is about displaying`TDateTime` values as dates in the debugger, but nothing about your particular request. It's not like nobody's ever mentioned it before, though. It's a perennial topic on the newsgroups; I just can't find anything in QC about it.

Your second idea would require `StrToDate` to be evaluable at compile time. I don't see any entries in QC about it either, but for what it's worth, C++ is getting such a feature for functions that are shown to have the necessary qualities. `StrToDate` wouldn't meet those requirements, though, because it's sensitive to the current locale's date settings.

Comment: EncodeDate, EncodeTime aren't affected and would suit the requirement.

Comment: Not quite, @Craig. One of C++'s requirements is that the function cannot throw exceptions (implicit in the requirement that the function consist solely of a `return` statement). The Delphi functions have compound statements and can throw.

Comment: A slight misunderstanding, I should have been less ambiguous in my comment. Allow me to elaborate: EncodeDate and EncodeTime aren't affected (by localisation - they're deterministic) and would suit the requirement (of Jim to specify a constant date/time, albeit syntactically different to his question). Of course the idea is a moot point since Delphi currently doesn't have such a feature. :( However, your comment about C++'s no exception requirement is interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Rob Kennedy's answer shows that the StrToDate solution is inherently out of the question as you don't want your code to break if it's compiled in Europe!

I do agree there should be some way to do EncodeDate but there isn't.

As far as I'm concerned the compiler should simply compile and run any code it finds in a constant assignment and store the result into the constant.  I'd leave it up to the programmer to ensure the code isn't sensitive to it's environment.

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to create a list of constants for years, another for month offsets and then build it on the fly.  You would have to take care of leap years yourself by adding 1 to each resulting constant.  Just a few below to get you started... :)

```
Const
  Leap_Day = 1;  // use for clarity for leap year dates beyond feb 29.
  Year_2009 = 39812;  // January 1, 2009
  Year_2010 = Year_2009 + 365; // January 1, 2010
  Year_2011 = Year_2010 + 365; // January 1, 2011
  Year_2012 = Year_2011 + 365; // January 1, 2012 (is leap year)
  Year_2013 = Year_2012 + Leap_Day + 365;  // January 1, 2013

Const
  Month_Jan = -1; // because adding the day will make the offset 0. 
  Month_Feb = Month_Jan + 31; // 31 days more for the first day of Feb.
  Month_Mar = Month_Feb + 28; // 28 days more for the first day of Mar.  
  Month_Apr = Month_Mar + 30; // 30 days more for the first day of Apr.

Const
  Expire_Jan1 : tDateTime = Year_2009 + Month_Jan + 1;
  Expire : tDateTime = Year_2009 + Month_Mar + 23;
```

If you have a leap year then you have to add 1 to anything beyond february of that year.

```
Const
  Expire : tDateTime = Year_2008 + Month_Mar + 23 + Leap_Day;
```

**EDIT**

Added a few more years for clarity, and added a Leap_Day constant.

Comment: Why not add another constant: Leap_day = 1.  That way there's no spurious "+1" sitting around that may not be intuitive at first glance...

Answer (score 3):

A Delphi date is the # of [days since Dec 30, 1899](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TDateTime).  So you could probably come up with an elaborate mathematical formula to express a date as a const.  Then you could format it very oddly, to emphasize the human-readable parts.  My best attempt is below, but it is very much incomplete; for one thing, it assumes that all months have 30 days.

My example is mostly for fun though.  In practice, this is pretty ridiculous.

```
const
  MyDate = ((
           2009  //YEAR
                                          - 1900) * 365.25) + ((
           3     //MONTH
                                          - 1) * 30) +
           24    //DAY
           ;
```

Comment: the fractional part also can cause problems as your date slowly moves from midnight one year, to 6 am, noon, 6pm to return again on leap year to midnight.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely true.  Like I said, this is not really workable unless you spend a lot of time devising a really sophisticated forumla to handle all possibilities.  Much better off just getting the value and hard-coding it.

Comment: And you may have a very hard-to-find bug if you accidentally get a digit or operator or bracket wrong in the "margin". Not going to downvote, but please don't do this in real code.

Answer (score 1):

i think *the* best solution available to you is to declare:

```
ArmisticeDay: TDateTime = 6888.0 + (11.0/24.0); //Nov 11, 1918 11 AM
```

and just accept it.

---

**My attempt Nº1**

```
Expire = EncodeDate(2009, 3, 23);
```

> [Error] Constant expression expected

**My attempt Nº2**

```
Expire: TDateTime = EncodeDate(2009, 3, 23);
```

> [Error] Constant expression expected

So even though they're constant, and deterministic (i.e. do not depend on any locale information), it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The type "TDateTime" = type "Double".

Algorithm:

1. Use **StrToDateTime('01.01.1900 01:01:01')** *(or other way)* to calculate need double_value. ('01.01.1900 01:01:01' => 2.04237268518519)

2.**const
DTZiro: TDateTime = 2.04237268518519;**

Comment: The OP always knows this.

Answer (score 1):

System.DateUtils has constants for each part of time.

```
const cDT : TDateTime = (12 * OneHour)   + ( 15 * OneMinute) 
                      + (33 * OneSecond) + (123 * OneMillisecond);
```

Comment: That is really creative. I didn't think of that.